# Is there a way to determine if code has been autogenerated by an AI source?

Tags: open-ai, chatgpt

Lately, our Junior developer has been producing code fixes very quickly. At first, I was excited for him as I thought he was starting to retain information and proving he was able to research and fix issues. But during our last code review, I was walking through his fixes and he couldn't speak to why he did was he did or what the code was actually doing. Obviously, OpenAI's Chat has taken off and I am just curious if there is a way to determine if code was generated by AI?

I did see that Stack Overflow has a policy on this [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) so it seems that they have a way to tell if the code is authentically written or not?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: This has been asked on SO Meta before: [How can we determine whether an answer used ChatGPT?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421880/how-can-we-determine-whether-an-answer-used-chatgpt)

Comment: This is concerning answers on SO. I am asking about general code and if it can be detected or not.

Comment: Did the code of all test cases?

Comment: @AzharKhan I assume you meant "Did the code pass all test cases?" 

So the code changes were made and worked then changes to test cases were made. But still hard to tell if the code was AI generated or not.

Comment: Just spend a few hours with him while he's developing, and ask him to change the code to do something else. Or start something new. Anyway if he's good enough to understand what gpt does and how to fix it, is it really a problem?